# Erro ao implementar compartilhamento para o facebook

Tags: php, css, html5, facebook

Segue o código que tenho:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Em seguida mais algum código:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $titulorowimvtopo ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $descricaorowimvtopo ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/cp/clientes/<?php echo $cliente ?>/<?php echo $idimovel ?>/<?php echo $idfototopoid; ?>" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="966242223397117" />
```

E por fim  a implementação para a exibição do botão compartilhar e curtir:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/detalhes.php?cliente=1&idimovel=6" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Como podem ver o código tem implementações PHP para dinamizar o processo, porém em todas as páginas a imagem, titulo e descrição são as mesmas. O que não deveria acontecer, uma vez que cada página possui seu próprio título, imagem e descrição.

Como resolver isso?

Comment: De onde está vindo `$titulorowimvtopo` e `$descricaorowimvtopo`? Tem certeza que estão corretos a cada página?

Answer (score 2):

Ao exibir o código fonte da página os dados estão corretos?
você pode usar as ferramentas do próprio facebook para verificar os erros em um determinado URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

Na hora de compartilhar que aparece sempre os mesmos dados certo? Se for, deve ser porque na `div` os dados estão estáticos, e não dinâmicos como na tag `meta`. Será que não é isso?

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/detalhes.php?cliente=<?php echo $cliente ?>&idimovel=<?php echo $idimovel ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```